# Probability of winning once in 10 draws

Tags: probability

If I entered the lottery, and the chance of winning was 5%, what are the chances I win at least once in 10 draws?
I've searched everywhere, but Google Calculator did not help me :(

Comment: Hint:  To find the probability of winning at least once, subtract the probability of not winning ten times from $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the probability that you win the lottery at least once. Determining this directly would be a little difficult so we compute $\mathcal{P}(A^c)$ i.e the probability that you never win any of the ten lotteries and then use the fact that $\mathcal{P}(A)+\mathcal{P}(A^c) = 1$.

The question now is how do we determine $\mathcal{P}(A^c)$. If we make the reasonable assumption that the probability of you losing once is independent of you losing at any other time then we can see that

$$\mathcal{P}(A) = 1-\mathcal{P}(A^c)   =1-\mathcal{P}(L)^{10}= 1 - (1-\frac{5}{100})^{10} \cong 0.4013$$ where $\mathcal{P}(L)$ denotes the probability of you losing a single lottery.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to me.